# Nested list to string

Tags: python, arrays, nested

I have a list of instances of class Test. This class have method like `name` and `parent`

```
[Test('a', ''), Test('b', ''), Test('c', 'a'), Test('d', 'a'), Test('e', 'c')]
```

First argument is name, second parent. Parent arg is simply a arg `name` of parent class.
I want convert this list to string like:

```
Test('a', '')
  |-- Test('c', 'a')
        |-- Test('e', 'c')
  |-- Test('d', 'a')
Test('b', '')
```

I looking for the most CPU-effective way to convert this list to string. Items in list can be nested at multiples (10,100, 1000, ..) levels, and I don't care about memory used.

Comment: Do you have a specific question or spot where you are stuck?  Can you post the code you've tried so far and are getting an error with, or are you looking for thoughts on best solution?

Comment: Edited. Sorry for this :) I looking for code or any idea to make this in CPU-effective way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that works as is. Basically convert the array into a tree and then use recursive DFS to print it (you can use iterative DFS if you want):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Test('"+self.name+"', '"+self.parent+"')"



li = [Test('a', ''), Test('b', ''), Test('c', 'a'), Test('d', 'a'), Test('e', 'c')]

dict = {"":(None,[])} #name to (node,children)
#add nodes
for item in li:
    dict[item.name] = (item, [])
#add children
for item in li:
    dict[item.parent][1].append(dict[item.name])

def printTree(dict, name, indent):
    newIndent=indent
    if name!="":
        print(indent + str(dict[name][0]))
        if indent == "": newIndent="  |-- "
        else: newIndent = "      "+indent
    for child in dict[name][1]:
        printTree(dict, child[0].name, newIndent) 


printTree(dict, "", "")
```

Comment: you create N references to each item (where N is the deepness). That code will be bad for large inputs...

Comment: you have: `{'': [a: [c: e, d], b], a: [c: e, d], b, c: e, d, e}`

Comment: you do realize that `dict["a"][1][0] is dict["c"]` is True in my code, right? There is exactly one object per name, just multiple references.

Comment: so there are only at most two references to each node - one in the dict and one from the parent

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote: "you create N references to each item"... still bad IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You should use another container, like that:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, sub=None):
        self.name = name
        self.sub = sub if sub is not None else []

elements = [Test('a', [Test('c', [Test('e')]), Test('d')]), Test('b')]
```

then just iterate `elements` to print:

```
def show(x, indent=0):
    for i in x:
        print('\t'*indent + 'Test(%r)' % i.name)
        show(i.sub, indent+1)

show(elements)
```

should print:

```
Test('a')
    Test('c')
        Test('e')
    Test('d')
Test('b')
```

You may change the indentation to anything you prefer (I'm using tabs).

Answer (score 0):

If you end up using DFS as fiver suggested you could use networkx

```
import networkx as nx
stuff=[('a', ''), ('b', ''), ('c', 'a'), ('d', 'a'), ('e', 'c')]
G=nx.DiGraph()
for i in stuff:
    G.add_edge(i[1],i[0])
print G.adj
```

Then it is a mater of iterating it with DFS